# provider: SNI_PN11, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified after installing MAUI Blazor App on ohter machin

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, blazor, maui

I have created a Maui Blazor app in .NET 7 which is pretty neat and runs beautifully locally.
After installing the app on another Windows 10 Pro x64 machine, I get an error message that Sql Server Express (2019) cannot be reached. I get this error message even if I set the connection string, of the target database explicitly in appsettings.json, before publishing the MAUI app.
Using a simple Winforms application I have validated the connection string before publishing.

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Error:
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SNI_PN11, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

SQL Server Management Settings:

- I have checked the SQL Server Remote setting
- I have checked the SQL Port and tried to set it to Default (1433)
- Remote connection is switched on
- TCP/IP are active
- Named Pipe is not present
- Firewall rules have already been created for: 135; 1433;1434;4022 & 1434 UDP created (inbound and outbound).
- Firewall is switched off
- The virus protection is turned off

SQL Profiler
At all attempts no event is logged in the trace log of the SQL-Profiler

I have created a small project that illustrates my circumstance. If you are interested you can have a look at it, compile it and install it on another machin/server.

Unfortunately I can't upload a sample project here to better explain my starting point

I'm pretty desperate because I just can't remember where I made a mistake.

Comment: _I have checked the SQL Port and tried to set it to Default (1433)_ Then why use an instance name in the connection string? The exception is happening because the SSRP call to resolve the instance name through the SQL Browser service is failing. Remove the instance name from the connection string and allow it to connect to the default port.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have checked all your suggestions and that was not the problem.
I have a link for you which will allow you to download my sample project (https://mycsharp.de/forum/posts/3840302). Search for "MauiGoesEntity.zip". This is from me.
Since I have not been working with MAUI for long, I ask for your indulgence.